# max per item within list of items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class C that has a List[B]  and each B has a Dictionary[A, double]

I need to select the max(double) per A 
currently i'm doing:

```
Dictionary<A,double> rtn = new Dictionary<A,double>();
foreach (var B in C.Bs)
{
    foreach (var kvpA in B.A_list.Where(a => !rtn.Keys.ToList().Contains(a)))
    {
        rtn.Add(kvpA.Key, kvpA.Value);
    }
    foreach(var kvpA in B.A_list.Where(a => rtn.Keys.Contains(a) && a.Value>rtn[a]))
    {
        rtn[kvpA.Key] = kvpA.Value;
    }
}
return rtn;
```

However this looks a fairly messy so i'm trying to build a better linq Query but can't figure out the syntax. any help?

Comment: _"...max(int) per A..."_ What are you talking about?

Comment: `B has a Dictionary[A, double]` - is that the `A_list` property? If so, this code doesn't compile: `B.A_list.Where(a => rtn.Keys.Contains(a)`

Comment: can you show the definitions for classes `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: @Tim I actually also need to convert the doubles to ints as well but thats easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume by max(int) you just meant "max", as in the maximum double per unique A accross all the `A_Lists`, which appear to actually be the dictionaries.

Anyway, you can do this all in three steps in a single LINQ statement:

1. Collapse all  key value pairs using [**SelectMany**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)
2. Group by unique A using [**GroupBy**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)
3. Take the max double per A key using [**ToDictionary**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx)

Where `c` is an instance of class `C`:

```
var dct = c.Bs.SelectMany(x => x.A_List)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max());
```

You could also use [**ToLookup**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) in place of ToDictionary, which would yield an IEnumerable iterator over the same `[A, double]` tuples as materialized by ToDictionary.

Comment: +1 you don't need the `Select(y=>y)` inside the `SelectMany`, but otherwise this is exactly what I came up with.

Comment: Thank you that looks like what i was after